# REST - if one result only, do I serve it as an object or as an array of one element?

Tags: ruby, json, http, rest

Let's say I have this url

`/thingies/active/`

I can have either 0, 1, or more than 1 active thingies. If I return just 1, do I return it as

```
{foo: "bar", baz: "quux"}
```

or

```
[{foo: "bar", baz: "quux"}]
```

How do you guys handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Return array of one element. I don't see any value in returning a single object in this special case. As well as returning something like `null` (instead of empty array) when no elements are found. Uniformity of API responses matters.

Comment: +1 returning an array in all cases (`[]`, `[1]`, `[1,2,3]`) makes it much easier to handle the result